# GOCD - Can we have a working directory for gradle/gradlew task to run

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, go-cd

I have multiple git materials for my pipeline which forces me to add working directories. Since gradle plugin does not have working directories, it does not find the gradlew or build.gradle.
Is there a way to come around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `environment` to GoCD which specifies your `PATH` variable including the gradle command:

[Using Environment Variables in GoCD](https://docs.go.cd/current/faq/environment_variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a gradle task you can try using a script executor task  -

https://github.com/gocd-contrib/script-executor-task

In the script executor task , you may execute gradle as given below

```
cd <Destination_Directory>
./gradlew <task>
```